# If $f:[a,b] \implies \mathbb{R}$ is discontinuous such that $f \geq 0$ does that imply $\int_a^bf=0 \implies f=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, continuity

is $f:[a,b] \implies \mathbb{R}$ is discontinuous with
$f \geq 0$

does $\int_a^bf=0 \implies f=0$ hold?

i know its true for continuous functions, but what about discontinuous?

edit: i meant the riemann inetgral

Comment: Consider the function whose value is $1$ at $0$, $0$ everywhere else. It is not the zero function, but all integrals $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ evaluate to $0$ for any $a\lt b$.

Comment: Considering Lebesgue-integration, this implies that $f$ is null almost everywhere.

Comment: If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable then it cannot be discontinuous everywhere.  What you can show (at an elementary level) is that if $f$ here is continuous at some point $x_0\in [a,b]$ then $f(x_0)=0$.  So $f$ must be discontinuous at every point $x$ at which $f(x)>0$.  The famous Thomae function (popcorn function) illustrates this with an example where $f$ is positive at each rational number (and hence discontinuous at each rational number). (As others point out, the answer is different for the Lebesgue integral, but students of the Lebesgue integral do not ask such questions.)

Comment: How to frame the answer depends in part what kind of integral you speak of. Riemann? Lebesgue?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Riemann